# Bluetooth module HC05 does not react to bluetooth signal from smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I try to switch off two leds with a hc05 module by sending the signal from my phone.
I know there are a lot of examples on the internet and I tried some of them, but they dont work either. I use a Elegoo Uno R3 and the "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" on my phone. When I try to send a 1 to the HC05 (slave) from my phone it just gives the 1 back, but does not seem to save it in the variable state.
I dont know if the two software serials can be a problem? But when I delete the the Software Serial it still does not work.
Here is my code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(8,9); // RX, TX
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;

void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);
char state;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);  //LED1
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);  //LED2
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));

  if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while(true){
      delay(0); // Code to compatible with ESP8266 watch dog.
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));

  myDFPlayer.volume(30);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  static unsigned long timer = millis();
  static unsigned long zeit = 0;

mySoftwareSerial.listen();
  if (millis() - timer > 900000) {    
    timer = millis();
    myDFPlayer.next();  //Play next mp3 every 10 minutes
    zeit = millis();
    while(millis()-zeit < 10000){
      digitalWrite(7, !digitalRead(7));  // toggle state
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(6, !digitalRead(6));
      delay (100);
    }
  }
Bluetooth.listen();
state = Bluetooth.read();
if (state == '1'){
   digitalWrite(6,LOW);
   delay(5000);
  }
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Best wishes,
CR

Comment: You tried to read bluetooth byte right after Bluetooth.listen(), which is probably why you don't receive anything. Instead wait for byte to be available using "while (Bluetooth.available() == 0);"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Fahad, but it still does not work. It appears that the condition Bluetooth.available() == 0 is always right...so it does not get a signal? I can, however, send something from the HC-05 to the phone.

Comment: Let's work with a simple example and just test the Bluetooth. Get rid of everything, except Bluetooth SoftwareSerial. If there is one SoftwareSerial you won't even need listen(). In the loop() just check if Bluetooth.available() is greater than zero or not. If is greater, read() and print().

Comment: Also listen() clears the SoftwareSerial buffer. Both of your SfotwareSerial uses the same buffer. So if you received anything before calling listen(), it is gone now.

Comment: I did that, but the available() is never greater than zero.

Comment: When I do: if(Bluetooth.available() ==0) {Bluetooth.write("something")}, it works, but not for read(). SO there is some kind of connection, but the available returns 0. Btw, (I dont know if this means anything) if I write something in the bluetooth terminal on my phone, the same thing comes back (from the hc05?). Like, if I write 1, it returns a 1.

Comment: Can you post your new code? Also, provide the link for bluetooth terminal. I have one HC-05. I can test on my end.

Comment: #include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(8,9); // RX, TX
char state;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);  //LED
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  if(Bluetooth.available()){
    state = Bluetooth.read();
    Serial.println(state);
    if (state == '1'){
      digitalWrite(3,LOW);
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=de

Comment: It worked as expected. So you might have different issues. If you can, edit your question, and add a connection, how did you connected your module with Arduino. Also, provide a link of the exact module you are using.

Comment: I dont know why, but it works now. Fahad, thank you very much for your effort :)